# Editing a loaded Wordpress option without updating the database

Tags: options

Is it possible to edit an option such as the `page_on_front` setting in a local scope, without updating the option in the database? For instance, I am attempting to serve a different homepage to logged in users, and via [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039607/different-wordpress-front-page-for-logged-out-and-logged-in-users) it is suggesting that I use `is_user_logged_in()` and then call `update_option( 'page_on_front', $page->ID )` to whichever id I want based on that status. However, the `update_option()` function actually updates the option in wp_options with every page load, which seems like unnecessary overhead to me. Is there a way to just edit whichever variable or object is holding that value when someone hits a page?

Comment: You might be able to use the `pre_get_posts` filter - check if it's the main query and is for the homepage; if the user is logged in change the query to grab a different post ID than what's currently set.

Comment: @WebElaine Thanks. Worse case I can also just use `is_logged_in()` in a custom homepage template and run different a custom `wp_query()` based on that, but I was still curious if there were a way to just set the homepage. I tried doing it with:

`$objcache = $GLOBALS['wp_object_cache'];
$objcache->page_on_front = "11";`

But it seemed to have no effect.

Comment: Maybe try `wp_cache_replace` - https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Object_Cache - I would just be concerned and want to verify that a change would not get cached for everyone viewing the site at the time, just the current user.